# How to group this activerecord association using ActiveRecord so that I can clean up the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have the following association:

`user.apples`

```
=> {
   id: 1,
   kind: "red delicious",
   rotten: true
   branch: nil
},
{
   id: 2,
   kind: "red delicious",
   rotten: nil
   branch: 5
},
{
   id: 3,
   kind: "granny smith",
   rotten: true
   branch: nil
},
{
   id: 4,
   kind: "granny smith",
   rotten: nil
   branch: 3
},
{
   id: 5,
   kind: "fuji",
   rotten: false
   branch: nil
},
{
   id: 4,
   kind: "fuji",
   rotten: nil
   branch: 1
}
```

So there's some duplicate data that I need to clean up. There really should only be an apple of every `kind` so I need to group them together so that I can iterate over the couple of apples that are duplicates of each other and combine them. I'd like my first step to look like this:

```
{
 "red delicious" => [{
   id: 1,
   kind: "red delicious",
   rotten: true
   branch: nil
},
{
   id: 2,
   kind: "red delicious",
   rotten: nil
   branch: 5
}],
"granny smith" => [
{
   id: 3,
   kind: "granny smith",
   rotten: true
   branch: nil
},
{
   id: 4,
   kind: "granny smith",
   rotten: nil
   branch: 3
}],
etc...
}
```

Is there a way to do an ActiveRecord type query? I'd love to offload the work to the database as much as possible here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `group_by`:

```
user.apples.all.group_by(&:kind)
```

This would give you an array with each `kind` as key with an array value containing all the apples which name is equal to the hash key:

```
{
  "red delicious"=>[
    #<Apple:0x007f9cb1cc0ba0 id: 1, kind: "red delicious", rotten: true, branch: nil>,
    #<Apple:0x007f9cb1cc0038 id: 2, kind: "red delicious", rotten: nil, branch: "5">
  ],
  "granny smith"=>[
    #<Apple:0x007f9cb1cb3888 id: 3, kind: "granny smith", rotten: true, branch: nil>,
    #<Apple:0x007f9cb1cb3428 id: 4, kind: "granny smith", rotten: nil, branch: "3">
  ],
  "fuji"=>[
    #<Apple:0x007f9cb1cb3220  id: 5,  kind: "fuji",  rotten: false,  branch: nil>,
    #<Apple:0x007f9cb1cb2f50  id: 6,  kind: "fuji",  rotten: nil,  branch: "1">
  ]
}
```